# int and double calculations

Tags: c++, int, double

I have a problem where I'm trying to set a double value but it keeps giving me int value.

Example:

```
int length;
double width;
double area =0;

setArea (getArea() + length * width);
```

Area will turn out to be int value.

I have tried

```
double newLength = static_cast<double>(length);
```

or

changing to

```
double length;
```

before setting the area but does not work. Oddly, when I use an actual integer such as 10 in place of length or an actual decimal in place of width, it works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "it keeps giving me an int value" ?

Comment: try (double)(getArea() + length * width);

Comment: Apologies, human error. Was actually reading off the wrong data file. Spent hours on this......

Comment: From what I see, both length and width are unitialised variables. Also you haven't provided signatures of setArea() and getArea() functions. What are the return values in setArea() and getArea()?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please show us the declaration for `setArea()?`  If it takes an `int` as a parameter, then 'area' will always be truncated to an `int`.

```
#include <iostream>

void setAreaInt(int newArea);
void setAreaDouble(double newArea);

int length;
double width;
double area = 0;

using namespace std;

int main () {

    length = 19;
    width = 4.3;
    setAreaInt (length * width);
    std::cout << area << endl;
    setAreaDouble (length * width);
    std::cout << area << endl;

    return 0;
}

void setAreaInt(int newArea) {
    area = newArea;
}


void setAreaDouble(double newArea) {
    area = newArea;
}
```

Output:

```
81
81.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies here in the following statements

```
    int length;
    double width;
    double area =0;

    setArea (getArea() + length * width);
```

getArea should return a `double` value typecast the value before returning

Also length is int type again typecast it to `double` in set area so it will be like this

```
setArea ((double)getArea() + (double)length * width);
```

also define `double area =0`; as `double area =0.0f`;

Comment: `f` following a number literal will make it a `float`

Comment: That is fine i understand but that will at least give the correct result for time being . or user can put a typecast there for double :)

Comment: Given `int length; double width;`, the expression `length * width` will convert `length` to `double` before doing the multiplication. Though I have to wonder why `length` and `width` are of different types in the first place.